# .eq() method is not giving same result as [ == ]

Tags: python, pytorch

I am having a hard time understanding why the results are not the same for following code.

I am trying to find the accuracy of a model but the first item gives a result of tensor(66.), and second item gives a result of tensor(105).

```
(y_test[y_test==y_predicted_cls].sum(), y_predicted_cls.eq(y_test).sum())
```

Both of the tensors (y_test and y_predicted_cls) have the same data type, torch.float32.
Output:

```
(tensor(66.), tensor(105))
```

I thought that first one would be equal to the second one.

Comment: The first one sums the elements of `y_test` which are equal to `y_predicted_cls`, the second sums the array of `1` and `0` that encodes elementwise equality. I.e. the second corresponds to (y_test==y_predicted_cls).sum(). This is also the reason why the first outputs a float and the second one gives back an integer.

Comment: I think actually @RoshinRaphel is right and what I wrote is not correct. I thought the `==` operator works for tensors like for numpy arrays which seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `y_test[y_test==y_predicted_cls].sum()` gives the sum for the `y_test` list/array while, `y_predicted_cls.eq(y_test).sum()` gives the sum for `y_predicted_cls`, and in the first case, if both the arrays are same, it yields:

```
y_test[1].sum()
```

else :

```
y_test[0].sum()
```